# The symbol "PROCEDURE" was ignored

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm getting this error:

> SQL> execute procedure hr.p_empleados_limites('Executive');
>
> begin procedure hr.p_empleados_limites('Executive'); end;
>
> line 1, column 7:  Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when expecting
>   one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise
>   return select update while with       <<    continue close current
>   delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute
>   commit forall merge pipe purge The symbol "PROCEDURE" was ignored.

While trying to run this Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_SALARIO (P_APELLIDO VARCHAR2 ) 
IS  
-- CURSOR EXPLICITO
CURSOR CUR IS 
        SELECT E.LAST_NAME, D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, ((NVL(E.COMMISSION_PCT,0)*E.SALARY)+E.SALARY) SAL_TOT
        FROM HR.EMPLOYEES E, HR.DEPARTMENTS D
        WHERE D.DEPARTMENT_ID=E.DEPARTMENT_ID AND
              E.LAST_NAME =P_APELLIDO;

       V_CUR CUR%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN CUR;
    LOOP
         FETCH CUR INTO V_CUR;
         EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('APELLIDO: '||V_CUR.LAST_NAME||' DEP_NOM:   '||V_CUR.DEPARTMENT_NAME ||  ' - SALARIO:' || V_CUR.SAL_TOT);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CUR;
END;
```

----execute procedure hr.p_salario('King');

Comment: This looks a lot like an oracle procedure & syntax. Definitely none of this will work in SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the word `procedure` while calling it. It should just be like

```
 execute hr.p_empleados_limites 'Executive';
```

(OR)

```
 exec hr.p_empleados_limites 'Executive';
```

Comment: @LuisAdriánTobar, welcome and consider accepting the answer if it helped by clicking the check button. Pointing it since you are a new user.